# Store data of each iteration of a LOOP and return all of them on a ref cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Sorry for the bad question name, i'll give you an example to be more specific.

```
 var1 VARCHAR(20);
 var2 VARCHAR(20);

  --MYRECORD CONTAINS COLUMNS ELEMENT0, VAL

     FOR MYRECORD IN EXPLICITCURSOR LOOP
     SELECT COL1, COL2 INTO var1, var2 FROM table1 WHERE table1.COLUMNT=MYRECORD.VAL;
     END LOOP;
```

As you can see i have a LOOP and inside it i have a SELECT. By now, for testing, i'm saving the results into two variables overwritten everytime.
I need to save on each iteration (ELEMENT0, COL1, COL2) and i'd give them on output with a REF CURSOR.

EDIT1: I'm looking in this moment on the possibility to define a RECORD and a TABLE of my record type. Can anyone give me an example for my case? I'm having problems on setting a table as output parameter.
This is what i have prepared at the beginning of the package.

```
TYPE my_record is RECORD(
   ELEMENT0      varchar2(20),
   COL1          varchar2(20),
   COL2          varchar2(20));

TYPE my_table IS TABLE OF my_record;
```

and for now i'm using an OUT parameter for my procedure like this:

```
TABLERESULT                            OUT my_table
```

I'm trying to insert my three varchar values inside my OUT param on each iteration of LOOP in this way (values are setted correctly):

```
INSERT INTO TABLERESULT(ELEMENT0,COL1,COL2) VALUES(ELEMENT0,COL1,COL2);
```

and it gives me error:

```
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

I'm doing something wrong using this type of OUT param?

Any suggestions? Thank you. (I'm using Oracle 11g)

EDIT2: By the help of @APC i found that naming error and now the compiler doesn't give problems. I'll continue and i'll let you know.

Comment: Save where?   a table?  a file?

Comment: With "save" i mean that i need a way to store those three varchar2 values in  something like an array and then return all of them with a ref cursor to the procedure caller. Can you advice a way  to do that?

Comment: Insert them into a temporary table?

Comment: Isn't an other way to handle a "simple" thing like this on pl/sql? I don't think that create a temporary table and later query it with my output ref cursor is the best way. Thank you anyway for the support.

Comment: Compare `TYPE` **`my_table`** `IS TABLE OF my_record;` with `TABLERESULT OUT ` **`mytable`** . Is there any difference between those two names? Something which might reasonably cause the compiler to assert that you are referencing a variable by a name it doesn't recognise?

Answer (score 0):

Create an object type that matches your record structure.

Create a nested table type of those object types.

For each tuplet of strings, add to the array.

Then return a cursor variable as follows:

OPEN cv FOR SELECT FROM TABLE (my_array);
RETURN cv;

The table function converts the array into a result set that can be assigned to the cursor variable.

Here's a link to a LiveSQL script that will run the code you see below: 
https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_FFTOKNC4AHGPOQE79FF76S7EQ.html

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE three_ot
   AUTHID DEFINER IS OBJECT
(
   element0 VARCHAR2 (200),
   col1 VARCHAR2 (200),
   col2 VARCHAR2 (200)
)
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE three_nt IS TABLE OF three_ot
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION data_for_you
   RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
   AUTHID DEFINER
IS
   l_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR;
   l_nt       three_nt;
BEGIN
   SELECT three_ot (TO_CHAR (employee_id), last_name, first_name)
     BULK COLLECT INTO l_nt
     FROM hr.employees;

   OPEN l_cursor FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE (l_nt);

   RETURN l_cursor;
END;
/

DECLARE
   l_cursor   SYS_REFCURSOR := data_for_you ();
   l_three    three_ot;
   element0   VARCHAR2 (200);
   col1       VARCHAR2 (200);
   col2       VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
   LOOP
      FETCH l_cursor INTO element0, col1, col2;
      EXIT WHEN l_cursor%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (col1);
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE l_cursor;
END;
/
```

Comment: Ok, like i said in my edit in this moment i have problems in the first two points. If you'll find some time it could be amazing to know just a bit on how i can achieve that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here this can be achieved simply without any iterations required.
Hope below snippet helps. Please pardon any syntax error as i dont have any workspace to execute this command.

```
--Wwhat i would suggest is rather going row-by-row this can be achieved by single iteration and can be returnedas ref cursor as output.

DECLARE
  lv sys.odcivarchar2list;
  lv_ref sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  SELECT val BULK COLLECT
  INTO lv
  FROM TABLE2;

  OPEN lv_ref FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.COL IN
  (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(lv)
  );
END;
/
```

Comment: I agree. In my example I also use bulk collect instead of a loop. And yes you can leave off TABLE and just reference the collection. Haven't yet adjusted to that relatively recent enhancement. Nice!